# Moped::BSON::ObjectId or String for parent's id in Rails models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, relationship, objectid

I'm new to MongoDB and Mongoid, using `Mongoid 3.1.4` for my Rails (`3.2.13`) app. I saw in the legacy code people using both `type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId` and `type: String` somewhere for the referenced model.

Example

```
class Team
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :room_id, type: String
  field :leader_id, type: Moped::BSON::ObjectId

  ...
end
```

(Using `git blame` I know these 2 lines written by 2 different people)

I did a search but haven't found the answer for the question when/why to use what type? `String` or `Moped::BSON::ObjectId`

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are a bit odd, you'd usually make relations instead of storing the id directly either as a string or an ObjectId:

```
class Team
  include Mongoid::Document

  belongs_to :room
  belongs_to :leader

  ...
end
```

This will also allow you to read the id directly by calling room_id or leader_id.
For more info check out http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html or http://two.mongoid.org/docs/relations.html

If I'd have to choose between the two I'd store the ObjectId instead of the string though, it takes less storage space.

Comment: Storing the ObjectId also avoids a big mess of type conversion nonsense when you're querying things. ObjectIds and strings often look the same but they're not; sometimes Mongoid will convert strings to ObjectIds for you, sometimes it won't.